# Creating a nested dictionary

Tags: python

Let say I have a list and a dictionary respectively:

```
a=['a.pdf','b.pdf']

b = {'a':['email1', 'email2'], 'b':['email3']}
```

And I want the end result to look like this nested dictionary using a loop.

```
x={'a.pdf':{'a':['email1', 'email2']}, 'b.pdf':{'b':['email3']}}
```

I tried using a for loop like this:

```
for element in a:
    x={}
    for key, value in b.items()
       x[element]={}
       x[found][key]=value

 print(x)
```

This doesn't work because  `dict x` is getting reassigned new values through each iteration so the end result is:

```
 {'b.pdf':{'b':['email3']}}
```

So I assume a dict comprehension is the way to go? I'm having a tough time figuring out how to write this into a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Why not move `x = {}` *outside* the `for` loop?

Comment: hmm would that fix my issue? Let me check.

Comment: Ha- it sure did... Thank you! But just for my curiosity, can someone write this using a dict comprehension as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['a.pdf','b.pdf']
>>> b = {'a':['email1', 'email2'], 'b':['email3']}
>>> c = {x: dict((y,)) for x, y in zip(a, b.items())}
>>> print c
{'a.pdf': {'a': ['email1', 'email2']}, 'b.pdf': {'b': ['email3']}}
```

Comment: If you dont mind, can you explain what the `dict((y,))` does in this instance?

Comment: In this case, `y` is a tuple with 2 elements such as: `('a', ['email1', 'email2'])` so you have to wrap it up with extra parenthesis either via `[y]` or `(y,)` notation in order to convert to a dictionary.

Comment: Doesn't the zip depend too much on the order of the items of `b`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
a=['a.pdf','b.pdf']
b = {'a':['email1', 'email2'], 'b':['email3']}
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(a,b.items())}
```

Result:

```
print(new_dict)
{'a.pdf': ('a', ['email1', 'email2']), 'b.pdf': ('b', ['email3'])}
```

Comment: i think it is wrong since inner tuple should be dict as well such as  `{'a': ['email1', 'email2']}`

Comment: I didn't even realize. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {top_key: {sub_key: b[sub_key] for sub_key in b if sub_key == top_key[0]} for top_key in a}
```

Assuming the key format you were using in your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a.pdf','b.pdf','c.pdf']
b = {'a':['email1', 'email2'], 'b':['email3']}
def match(m):
    return m[0]
d = { e: {match(e): b[match(e)]} for e in a if match(e) in b }
```

You can change the match func to your requirement.